# What is the best way to put red frame above green container flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: Example] Hallo, as example displayed, I would like to put a red frame container above the green container, currently I'm using Stack as following code:

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          greenContainer,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            redContainerFrame,
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

But I am afraid, since the page is responsive, so the size of green container and red frame could become really big, and current solution is not a good one, or I need to detect the screen size and setState the Positioned size? Or Flutter has a better idea that I dont know, thank you in advance for any clue!

======================== **Update** ========================

sorry I made my question not clear, I dont mean to add just a red frame or border like above red one, actually it will be like following frame/ an Image:

[image: a picture]

so actually it will be such png picture above anther png picture, and this part confuses me how to coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the Stack in a SizedBox and give the SizedBox the dimensions of your frame. Then the Center widget can be used as child of the Stack to position another picture in the middle.

```
SizedBox(
  height: height of frame,
  width: width of frame,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Image.network(
        "link to frame image",
      ),
      Center(
        child: Image.network(
          "link to center image",
          width: define with or height to be sure its smaller than the frame image,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

**1st Way** *using border of container*

```
 Container(
          height: 250,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 15,
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: 250,
            width: 150,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**2nd Way** *using margin*

```
  Container(
          height: 250,
          width: 150,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Hi Ravindra thank you for your comment, plz check my update

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `border` from container decoration for red.

```dart
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 300,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green,
      border: Border.all(
        width: 12, //red frame
        color: Colors.red,
      )),
)
```

More about [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [`BoxDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)

Comment: Hi Yeasin thank you for your comment, plz check my update

Answer (score 0):

Use BoxDecoration and border property like this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 10)),
  color: Colors.green,
),
```